# Remove a ROW of NULL entries SQl Server

Tags: sql, rows

If I have a table which looks like this

[image]

Is there a way to remove all rows in a SQL tablw without knowing the column titles, if each item in that row is NULL?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this using dynamic SQL / prepared statements.  The syntax varies by database.  Within a given database, there *might* be a hack that would accomplish this, but that would be very database specific.  In other words, tag the question with the database.

Comment: ...also, why do you need this "hack" at all? Why don't you know the columns?

Comment: Is there no key or anything to identify rows?

Comment: Since you've tagged `SqlCommand`: Nameless, also called ordinal, parameters are not supported by the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server.

Comment: the database will never be constant, this is just an example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way but since you've tagged `SqlCommand` i would use  ADO.NET. You can use `dataReader.GetSchemaTable` to retrieve column informations only:

```
// retrieve column names only
DataTable schema = null;
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var schemaCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}

// build sql with parameters dynamically
var columnQuery = schema.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => string.Format("{0} IS NULL", r.Field<String>("ColumnName")));
string where = string.Join(" AND ", columnQuery);
string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM dbo.TableName WHERE {0}", where);
// here you are
```

Of course you need two queries, one to select the columns and one to delete the null-rows. So the best way would be to know the columns in the first place.

Comment: have removed the sql command - looking for a query. thanks though

Comment: it's to fit in with an odbc library i've written so I was really only looking for a sql query if one existed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that should allow you to first **SEE** what your delete statements will look like, and then run it again when you're ready to actually perform the deletions:

```
begin
    set nocount on

    create table #temp_sql_text (sql_text varchar(max))

    declare @table_name varchar(max)

    declare c cursor for
    select name from sys.tables order by name

    open c
    fetch next from c into @table_name

    while @@fetch_status = 0   
    begin
        insert into #temp_sql_text
        select 'delete from ' + @table_name + ' where ' + replace(stuff(ColumnList, 1, 3, ''), '|||', ' is null and ') + ' is null'
        from ( 
            select '|||' + '[' + c.name + ']'
            from sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
            where t.name = @table_name
            order by c.column_id
            for xml path('') 
        ) o (ColumnList)

        fetch next from c into @table_name
    end   

    close c
    deallocate c

    declare @sql_text varchar(max)

    declare c2 cursor for
    select sql_text from #temp_sql_text

    open c2
    fetch next from c2 into @sql_text

    while @@fetch_status = 0   
    begin
        --Suggest just printing out the delete queries as a test before executing them!
        print @sql_text
        --Uncomment the next line to also execute the delete queries
        --exec sp_executesql @sql_text
        fetch next from c2 into @sql_text
    end   

    close c2
    deallocate c2

    drop table #temp_sql_text

    set nocount off
end
```

Comment: @MarkCorrigan You have multiple answers posted, using various methods, most of which will accomplish your goal. Would you mind marking one of them as your answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this: I just tried on SQL server 2008 R2. I am not good with how to place the code in answer. please bare it.

```
declare @tempvar as nvarchar(max)

set @tempvar='X'

select @tempvar=@tempvar+COLUMN_NAME+' is NULL AND ' from 
DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='Table_Name'

print @tempvar

Select @tempvar=CONCAT(@tempvar, 'X')

print @tempvar

Select @tempvar= REPLACE(@tempvar,'AND X','')

print @tempvar

Select @tempvar= REPLACE(@tempvar,'X',' ')

print @tempvar

declare @queryex as nvarchar(max)

set @queryex='select * from Table_Name where'+@tempvar

print @queryex

EXEC sp_executesql @queryex
```

Comment: I have used @queryex as Select statement but you can change it or modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: The OP asked to *REMOVE* the rows (i.e. `DELETE`), not simply to `SELECT` them.

Comment: I have already mentioned that i have tested code for select statement. You can easily change value of @queryex variable from select to delete. Still if you want, here is the line you should apply instead of select.

set @queryex='delete from Table_Name where'+@tempvar

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of columns in the table, you can do this:

```
delete from 
    tableToScrub
where
    checksum(*) = 
    checksum(
        cast(null as int), 
        cast(null as int)
        -- Add one null to checksum per column
    )
```

If you don't know the number of columns, you can do this:

```
with 
    nullset 
as  (
    select 
        cast(null as int) as col1,
        cast(null as int) as col2, 
        cast(null as int) as col3, 
        cast(null as int) as col4, 
        cast(null as int) as col5, 
        cast(null as int) as col6, 
        cast(null as int) as col7
        -- add columns as necessary for your tables
    )
,
    nullchecksums 
as (
    select checksum(col1) as nullsum, 1 as columnCount from nullset union
    select checksum(col1, col2), 2 from nullset union
    select checksum(col1, col2, col3), 3 from nullset union
    select checksum(col1, col2, col3, col4) , 4 from nullset union
    select checksum(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) , 5 from nullset union
    select checksum(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) , 6 from nullset union
    select checksum(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) , 7 from nullset
    -- add rows as necessary
)

delete from
    tableToScrub
where
    checksum(*) = (
        select
            nullsum
        from
            nullchecksums
        where
            columncount = (
                select 
                    count(1) as columnCount 
                from
                    sys.columns
                where
                    object_id =  object_id('SchemaName.TableToScrub')
            )
    )
```